# Add a value to dictionary within a dictionary error

Tags: c#

i am using the following code:

```
private Dictionary<string, user> totalUsers = new Dictionary<string, user>();
```

the relevant part from "user" class

```
private Dictionary<DateTime,string> killerField;

public Dictionary<DateTime,string> killedPlayers
{
    get
    {
        return this.killerField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.killerField = value;
    }
}
```

how i am trying to do this action

```
totalUsers[playerName].killedPlayers.Add(DateTime.Now, dyingPlayer);
```

but i am getting an error:

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
```

why it aint working?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if this.killedPlayers is not null

Comment: Maybe rewrite `private Dictionary<DateTime,string> killerField;` to be `private Dictionary<DateTime,string> killerField = new Dictionary<DateTime,string>();` unless you have a reason for having it `null` at any given time.

Answer (score 3):

You must create an instance of `killerField` before you can `Add` anything. At the point of adding a player it hasn't yet been created using `new Dictionary<DateTime,string>()`.

You can do this as part of the declaration or alternatively in the class constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You most probably haven't initialized the dictionary killerFields, hence you can't add to it.

Comment: @dan: You show that you _declare_ it, but not _initialize_ it (very important difference). Where do you assign a `new Dictionary<DateTime,string>()` to it?

Answer (score 0):

Because totalUsers[User] isn't in your dictionary.  And besides, you defined totalUsers to have a String key, that returns a User object.  Then you reference it with a User key.  You need to fill TotalUsers, and then get users out by some string token.

Like this:

```
string userName = "yourusertoken";
totalUsers[userName].killedPlayers.Add(someDate,somestring);
```

Comment: read agian User is not a class is a string - yeah it can be confusing, i will edit it to be more clear.

Comment: Ok.  Before you try to reference totalUsers[playerName], make sure it's in the dictionary with totalUsers.ContainsKey(playerName);  If that returns true, then KillerField has not been initialized to a new dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I am 100% sure the following solution will work if the code provided by you is correct.

```
if(!totalUsers.ContainsKey(playerName))
{
    totalUsers.Add(playerName, new User());
    //or
    //totalUsers[playerName] = new User();  
}

//and then you can do actions on the initialized value in the dictionary

totalUsers[playerName].killedPlayers.Add(DateTime.Now, dyingPlayer);
```

you should also instantinate the dictionary inside the class, maybe in the constructor

```
private Dictionary<DateTime,string> killerField = new Dictionary<DateTime,string>();
```